# route locating in a box like 2-d array

Tags: c, algorithm

**MY CODE:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int ch,a[100];
static int i=0,j;
int checkIfValidCoordinates(int x, int y, int n, char arr[]){
    if(x==a[i]&& y==a[i+1])
    {
        i+=2;
        return 0;
    }    
    // arr for this location is invalid
    // then return 0;
    return 1;
}
void path(int u,int v,int n,char arr[],size_t s,size_t p)
{
    ch=1;
    int x;
    j=checkIfValidCoordinates(u,v,n,arr);
    if(j == 0)
        return;
    if(u==(n-1)&&v==(n-1))
    {
        p+=snprintf(arr+p,s-p,"( %d , %d )",u,v);
    }
    else
    {
         p+=snprintf(arr+p,s-p,"( %d , %d ) - ",u,v);
    }
    if(p>=s)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Small path\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(u==n-1&&v==n-1)
    {
        printf("%s\n",arr);
    }
    else
    {
    {

        if(u<n-1)
        {
            path(u+1,v,n,arr,s,p);
        }
        if(v<n-1)
        {
             path(u,v+1,n,arr,s,p);
        }
        if(u<n-1&&v<n-1)
        {
             path(u+1,v+1,n,arr,s,p);
        }
    }
    }
}
void main()
{
    char arr[1000];
    int size;
    printf("Enter the size of the grid");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    if(size<=0)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid Input");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nEnter the grid points that are offsets");
    here1:
    scanf("%d %d",&a[i],&a[i+1]);
    if(a[i]==-1&&a[i+1]==-1)
    {
        goto here;
    }
    else
    {
    i+=2;
    goto here1;
    }
    here:
    printf("\nThe paths for the robot are\n");
    i=0;
    path(0,0,size,arr,sizeof arr,0);
}
```

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:**
There is a grid through which the robot is moving.the robot is moving three direction.the directions are right down and diagonally down.the program is to find the path of the robot to reach its destination from the source which is top left of the matrix give.

**WHAT I EXPECT:**

My code prints all the paths for a robot in three direction...if i block any cell of a matrix then how will be the changes in the path...and how to print the path??

**Plz.. help me to do this...**

Comment: Use `int main()` instead of `void main()`

Comment: the offsets might not be in sorted order, check the whole array inside checkIfValidCoordinates

Comment: How to sort those limits...??  marvel308

Comment: can u give me the solution for this? miket25

Comment: plzzz...give me a solution guys

Comment: @rajrajan I should say that this site is not a coding service. People here are answering question on a volunteer basis. Giving solutions away to homework is not the purpose of this site, and you're not entitled to any solutions here. But we will help given your good-faith attempts.

Comment: @rajrajan Please do not vandalize your question. Removing the problem description and your code makes it useless for future visitors. I've rolled back the edits to include the full text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct point {
    int r, c;
} Point;

void search_path(Point p, int n, char (*blocks)[n], Point *path, size_t path_len){
    if(p.r == n || p.c == n || blocks[p.r][p.c])
        return;//invalid point
    path[path_len++] = p;//add point to path
    if(p.r == n-1 && p.c == n-1){//goal! print path
        for(size_t i = 0; i < path_len; ++i){
            if(i)
                putchar('-');
            printf("( %d , %d )", path[i].r, path[i].c);
        }
        puts("");
        return;
    }
    search_path((Point){ p.r +1, p.c    }, n, blocks, path, path_len);//down
    search_path((Point){ p.r   , p.c +1 }, n, blocks, path, path_len);//right
    search_path((Point){ p.r +1, p.c +1 }, n, blocks, path, path_len);//diagonally down
}

int main(void){
    int size = 0;

    printf("Enter the size of the grid\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    if(size <= 0){
        printf("\nInvalid Input\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Point *path = malloc((size * 2 - 1) * sizeof(*path));//check omitted
    char (*blocks)[size] = calloc(size, sizeof(*blocks));

    printf("\nEnter the grid points that are offsets\n");
    Point offset;
    while(scanf("%d %d", &offset.r, &offset.c)==2){
        if(offset.r == -1 && offset.c == -1)
            break;
        blocks[offset.r][offset.c] = 1;
    }

    printf("\nThe paths for the robot are\n");
    search_path((Point){0, 0}, size, blocks, path, 0);

    free(blocks);
    free(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input was a little unclear but basically you are trying to do something like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int ch,a[100];
static int i=0;
int checkIfValidCoordinates(int x, int y, int n, char arr[]){
    if(x<0 || y<0 || x>n-1 || y>n-1)
        return 0;
    // arr for this location is invalid
    // then return 0;
    return 1;
}
void path(int u,int v,int n,char arr[],size_t s,size_t p)
{
    if(checkIfValidCoordinates() == 0)
        return;
    if(u==(n-1)&&v==(n-1))
    {
        p+=snprintf(arr+p,s-p,"( %d , %d )",u,v);
    }
    else
    {
         p+=snprintf(arr+p,s-p,"( %d , %d ) - ",u,v);
    }
    if(p>=s)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Small path\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(u==n-1&&v==n-1)
    {
        printf("%s\n",arr);
    }
    else
    {
        if(u<n-1)
        {
            path(u+1,v,n,arr,s,p);
        }
        if(v<n-1)
        {
             path(u,v+1,n,arr,s,p);
        }
        if(u<n-1&&v<n-1)
        {
             path(u+1,v+1,n,arr,s,p);
        }

    }
}
void main()
{
    char arr[1000];
    int size;
    printf("Enter the size of the grid");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    if(size<=0)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid Input");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nThe paths for the robot are\n");
    i=0;
    path(0,0,size,arr,sizeof arr,0);
}
```

just add condition to your checkIfValidCoordinates function

Comment: if i block any cell i.e 0,1 then how the robot will track the path except 0,1...how it will?...thats what im asking

Comment: it cannot go to that path hence all other valid paths would only be traversed since the checks would pass on a node in a valid path only, so you'll print only valid paths

Comment: i just updated my code see whether it will work...plzz

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple mathematical observation to this problem that avoids a dynamic programming algorithm. Here is the observation to describe the process to help you write the code on your own.

First have an `NxN` matrix `M` where all entries are `-1`. Suppose `N = 3`. The matrix will be:

```
-1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1
```

Next fill in the offset squares with `0`. Let (1,1) be an offset square, so we mark it zero.

```
-1 -1 -1
-1  0 -1
-1 -1 -1
```

Mark the top row all `1s` and the left-most column `1s` **see edge case below*.

```
 1   1   1
 1   0  -1
 1  -1  -1
```

Here's the beautiful mathematical part, notice, at any given square that's nether on the top row or left-most column, the number of paths to that square is the sum of the upper, upper-left, left previous squares e.g. 
`M[i][j] = M[i-1][j] + M[i-1][j-1] + M[i][j-1]`. Traverse the matrix and for each `-1` square, calculate the sum for that square until the bottom is reached. **If a square is zero, ignore it and move on!**

```
1   1   1
1   0   2
1   2   4
```

Noticed each square is the sum of the upper, upper-left, and left square. The square on the right-most bottom is the answer of possible paths from the top-left origin to the bottom-right corner.

**Edge case:**
When you're marking squares as offset `0s`, if an offset square happens to be in the **top row** or **left-most column**, mark the respective direction ending with all zeros. Example, let (0,1) be an offset with `N = 3`, mark all squares of row 0, after (0,1) and including, to be zeros.

```
1   0   0
1  -1  -1
1  -1  -1
```

Comment: Thank You..micket25

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a string to record the path. Instead, use an array of directions taken each step. If you use a char array, then you can use

```
#define  RIGHT  1
#define  DOWN   2
/* Down-right is DOWN|RIGHT == RIGHT|DOWN */
```

Note that if the matrix has `N`×`N` cells, then the maximum length of the path is 2`N`-2. The length of a complete path varies from `N`-1 (a straight diagonal path) to 2`N`-2 (along two edges of the matrix).

Instead of finding the complete path, split it into individual steps. The stepping function takes one step, calling itself recursively, until the current path is blocked, or the walk reaches the desired cell.

In pseudocode, this step function is

```
Define  RIGHT = 1
Define  DOWN  = 2

Function Step(n, row, col, i, map[], path[]):
    # n               is the number of rows and columns in the map
    # row             is the current row
    # col             is the current column
    # i               is the number of steps already taken
    # map[n*row+col]  is nonzero if the cell is blocked
    # path[i]         is the direction for the next step

    # If we arrived at a blocked cell, this path
    # will not lead to target.
    If (map[n*row+col] != 0):
        Return
    End If

    # When we reach the target, we print the path.
    If (row == n-1) and (col == n-1):
        x = 0
        y = 0
        Print "(x,y)"
        For (j = 0; j < i; j++):
           If (path[j] & RIGHT) x++
           If (path[j] & DOWN)  y++
           Print "-(x,y)"        
        End For
        Print newline
        Return
    End If

    # If we can step right, we try that.
    If (col < size - 1):
        path[i] = RIGHT
        Step(n, row, col+1, i+1, map, path)
    End If

    # If we can step diagonally down, we try that.
    If (col < size - 1) and (row < size - 1):
        path[i] = DOWN | RIGHT
        Step(n, row+1, col+1, i+1, map, path)
    End If

    # If we can step down, we try that.
    If (row < size - 1):
        path[i] = DOWN
        Step(n, row+1, col, i+1, map, path)
    End If

    Return
End Function
```

Because the `Step()` function is recursive, at each step we split the current path into up to three different subpaths, depending on which step we take. (Because the path is at most 2`N`-2 steps long, our maximum recursive depth is also 2`N`-2. This means that we don't need to worry about running out of stack space due to the recursive calls.)

If we draw a graph, where we mark each node with `K: (X, Y)`, where `K` is the number of the recursive call (1 for first, 2 for second, and so on), and `X` and `Y` are the column and row, respectively, where in the matrix that `Step()` call is at, we get the following:

[image: Call graph corresponding to the recursive pseudocode shown]

(That graph was produced using C code implementing the above pseudocode, and a global counter incremented on each `Step()` call, by outputting each call as a node, and each recursive call as an edge, in Graphviz DOT format.)

As you can see, the first five recursive calls find the path that travels along the upper right edge of the matrix: `(0,0)-(1,0)-(2,0)-(2,1)-(2,2)`. The second path found splits from that in the second step, yielding `(0,0)-(1,0)-(2,1)-(2,2)`, and so on. Examining that graph, and considering which call corresponds to which step(s) in which path(s), should help you understand how such recursive path finders work.

Comment: Thank You...helpful