# Finding all paths in a NxN grid

Tags: c

Imagine a robot sitting on the upper left hand corner of an NxN grid. The robot can only move in three directions: right , down and diagonally down. The robot has to reach the lower right hand corner of the NxN grid. Imagine certain squares are “off limits” or “offsets”, such that the robot cannot step on them. Write a program to determine the number of possible paths for the robot.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int abc[50]={}, count=0;
int ak[5][5];

void called(int a,int b,int c){

if(a==c-1 && b==c-1){
    int i=0;
    printf("( 0 , 0 ) - ");
    for(i=0;i<count;i+=2){
        if(i==count-2)
        printf("( %d , %d )",abc[i],abc[i+1]);
        else
        printf("( %d , %d ) - ",abc[i],abc[i+1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    abc[count--]=-1;
    abc[count--]=-1;
    return;
}

else{
    if(a!=c-1 && ak[a][b]!=1){
        abc[count++]=a+1;
        abc[count++]=b;
        called(a+1,b,c);
    }
    if(b!=c-1 && ak[a][b]!=1){
        abc[count++]=a;
        abc[count++]=b+1;
        called(a,b+1,c);
    }
    if(a!=c-1 && a!=c-1 && ak[a][b]!=1){
        abc[count++]=a+1;
        abc[count++]=b+1;
        called(a+1,b+1,c);
    }
abc[count--]=-1;
abc[count--]=-1;
}

}


void main(){

int a,b,i,j,n;

printf("Enter the size of the grid\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

if(n>=0){
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
ak[i][j]=0;
printf("Enter the grid points that are offsets\n");
scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%d",&b);
while(a!=-1 && b!=-1){
    ak[a][b]=1;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%d",&b);
}
printf("The paths for the robot are\n");
called(0,0,n);
}

else
printf("Invalid Input");

getchar();

}
```

At runtime, an error pops up saying--

```
Program terminated due to "Segmentation fault" (11)
```

Comment: You get seg fault on compilation???

Comment: I recommend you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes such as this in your program.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45522468/971127)

Answer (score 0):

You take the grid size as an input, but you have also hard coded it to be 5 * 5. If a user tries to put in a higher number than 5 your program should crash with a "Segmentation fault".

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be coding this problem into a graph, by assigning a unique ID to each cell of the grid and then build either a list of adiacences or an adjacency matrix (if the graph is dense - with a lot of edges - prefer the matrix over the list).

This way you can use optimal pre-existent graph algorithms to find the number of all paths between two vertexes in said graph.

Answer (score 0):

Formula I derived for an nxn grid:  (2n)!/[(n!)(n!)]  In English: 2n factorial divided by n factorial squared.
Formula for an mxn grid:  (m+n)!/(m!n!)
For the nxn grid r
efer to Pascal's Triangle.  The answers are the numbers straight down the middle, namely 1, 2, 6, 20, etc.